# C# compiler allows interface in place of generic derived version?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, .net-2.0

I'm slightly baffled by some behaviour I don't understand from the compiler. I've reduced it to the following code sample:

```
    public interface IFoo { }
    public interface IBar<T> : IFoo { }
    public delegate void DHandler<T>(IBar<T> arg);

    public static class Demo
    {
        static void Garply<T>(DHandler<T> handler) { }

        public static void DoStuffWithInt()
        {
            Garply<int>(Handler);
        }

        static void Handler(IFoo arg) { }
    }
```

My problem is that I don't expect the code to compile, but it does. I don't expect it to compile because `DHandler<int>` requires `IBar<int>` in the signature, but the `Handler` method declares `IFoo`, which is *not* `IBar<int>` (although the converse is true). Hence `Handler` is not a `DHandler<int>` and so a delegate to it wouldn't be usable as an argument to a `Garply<int>` call.

If I change the code to read `Handler(IBar<int> arg)` it compiles. If I change it to read `Handler(IBar<string> arg)` it doesn't. Both those behaviours are as I'd expect.

The practical problem that prompts this question is that when the signature is `Handler(IBar<int> arg)`, the compiler complains that I need to explicitly specify the type parameter for the `Garply` call. Trivial in this example, but in the actual code it'll be a real nuisance. I was mystified, since the argument to `Garply` is a method with the signature `(IBar<int> arg)`, so the delegate to it would be a `DHandler<int>`, so the chosen `Garply<T>` would unambiguously be `Garply<int>`. But apparently the compiler saw an ambiguity. It was investigating that, that led me to the above puzzle and I can only guess that perhaps the compiler is thinking "well, to Jason's surprise, I'd have accepted an `IFoo` for this `IBar<T>`, so a `T` has to be specified to allow me to know that I should compile it as `IBar<T>` and not as `IFoo`". That might explain why it wants the type parameter. But can anyone cast light on this?

Comment: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is *delegate variance*, which was introduced in C# 2. This is *not* the same as the *generic* variance introduced in C# 4.

Here's an even simpler example:

```
delegate void Foo(string x);    

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = Bar;
    }

    static void Bar(object y) {}
}
```

The point is that we can create an instance of the `Foo` delegate from the `Bar` method because `Bar` will work provided it's given *any* `object`. When a `Foo` delegate is called, it will always provide a `string` reference, and there's a reference conversion from `string` to `object`. So if I have:

```
Foo f = ...;
f("fred");
```

... that call would *always* be appropriate for `Bar`.

Likewise in your case, any call that `Garply<T>` makes with `handler` would *definitely* be a valid call to `Handler` - so the compiler is happy to create an appropriate `DHandler<T>` instance.

The problem when `Handler` only accepts an `IBar<int>` is that the compiler doesn't use possible method group conversions for arguments when inferring type parameters. This is an area where type inference certainly *could* be stronger, and indeed it improved - in a very similar area, although I can never remember the details - between C# 3 and C# 4.

Comment: Ah, so the delegate issue is an unrelated red herring. In my question I was assuming the parameter would use delegate covariance but I should have expected contravariance. I'm afraid I've never actually used contravariance or any delegate variance, so it's alien to me. My bad - will make an appointment tomorrow to get my brain rotated 180 degrees!

As for my original problem - so it's obvious to a human what the type is and we can imagine the compiler "should" see it easily, but it doesn't. Fair enough, I'll try and rearchitect my way round it. Thanks!